# What does this code do? DllImport ExactSpelling

Tags: c#

What does this code do? I have tried researching it but I have had no luck.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is an attribute tag which is supposed to be placed above an external declaration of a method located in the `kernel32.dll` library.

In practice, you would see it associated with a method declaration similar to:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern bool MoveFile(string src, string dst);
```

See [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute(v=vs.71).aspx) for details on its usage.

Comment: But what does it do? is there much purpose in it. How will it effect my application?

Comment: By itself this line does nothing.  It needs to be associated with an `extern` method declaration.  I just edited my answer and added a link to an MSDN article which explains its usage in more detail.